# Access Dynamically Generated Elements in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am using an iFrame to load http://www.amazon.co.uk when i press Amazon UK button and it is loading as well and i browse into sub pages of amazon.co.uk. Now what i want is to get href attribute of  tags when i hover on  tags or links in this iFrame.
Is it possible with Javascript or jQuery Please tell me how?

--This is What i am doing

```
<div id="amazon_buttons">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="../../users/product" target="_top"><input id="cmdback" name="cmdback" type="button" value="Back To IEC" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="cmdanzuk" name="cmdanzuk" type="button" value="Amazon UK" onclick="open_amazon_page('uk')" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="cmdanzde" name="cmdanzde" type="button" value="Amazon DE" onclick="open_amazon_page('de')" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="cmdanzfr" name="cmdanzfr" type="button" value="Amazon FR" onclick="open_amazon_page('fr')" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="cmdanzes" name="cmdanzes" type="button" value="Amazon ES" onclick="open_amazon_page('es')" /> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<iframe id="azn_iframe" name="azn_iframe" src="" style="clear: both; width: 100%; height:800px;"></iframe>
```

> ```
>     $("#azn_iframe").contents().find("a").hover(
>     function () {
>         alert($(this).attr("href"));
>     });
>
>     function open_amazon_page($platform)
>     {
>         if($platform == 'uk')
>             azn_iframe.location.href = "http://www.amazon.co.uk";
>         else if($platform == 'de')
>             azn_iframe.location.href = "http://www.amazon.de";
>         else if($platform == 'fr')
>             azn_iframe.location.href = "http://www.amazon.fr";
>         else if($platform == 'es')
>             azn_iframe.location.href = "http://www.amazon.es";
>     }
> </script>
> ```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, because the iframe is in a different domain from yours. This limitation is a security measure imposed by the browser's [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

More reading:

- [Same origin policy for JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)
- [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)
- [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/chrome-disable-same-origin-policy)
- [What is the threat model for the same origin policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744283/what-is-the-threat-model-for-the-same-origin-policy)